# Running an executable jar file using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a project file which includes a jar file(monix.jar) and some data(models, plugins, ...). Developers didn't provide source code of it and I need to run it.
I'm working in the eclipse env and I tried this steps:

1. extracted it in my eclipse workspace(it was extracted under a folder named monix)
2. in the eclipse:Run > External Tools > External tools Configurations
3. set location in the Main tab to: D:\eclipse workspace\monix\data\gate\plugins\ANNIE\build.xml  (and ofcourse I tried this path too: D:\Program Files Project\Java\bin\java.exe)  by Brows File System button.
4. then set Working Directory to the path of project folder. D:\eclipse workspace\monix by Brows File System button.
5. Developers have provided a syntax for running it ($ ./monix inputDirectory outputDirectory) so I set Arguments according to this syntax ($ ./monix D:\monixinputs D:\monixoutput)

When I run it, there is an error:
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "D:\eclipse workspace\monix\data\gate\plugins\ANNIE\build.xml" (in directory "D:\eclipse workspace\monix"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I'm totally confused and really need your help,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any specific reason on why you running from eclipse ?...you can run a jar file using java -jar app.jar...check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

Comment: **is not a valid Win32 application** is it compiled in 64 bit OS and being run on a 32 bit OS ?

Answer (score 0):

**File.jar**

If you want only run the program you have to use this file. For run it open cmd or bash in Windows or Linux and write:

java -jar /Path_Of_Your_File/File.jar

(Be sure that you have environment variable "JAVA_HOME" correctly configured)

**Build.xml**

This isn't for run the program. This file is used, for example, for generate File.jar from the Java code.

**Run --> Run configuration in Eclipse**

Here you have to specify the name of your project and the name of the main class in your project, but if you haven't the code, you don't have to use this.

**D:\Program Files Project\Java\bin\java.exe**

This is java.exe, the virtual machine of Java, you don't have to execute this for run your project.